# Dynamic PHP Email with All Values from Database Table in HTML using Mysqli

Tags: php, email, mysqli, foreach

I'm a noob here, but I all I want to do here is to generate a PHP Mail using all the rows and their values from a Database Table using MYSQLi method.

My Table Format
**ndr_confirm_id** | **order_id** (INT) | **tracking_no** (BIGINT) | **status** (0,1) | **update_time**
Estimated Rows in the Table : 50-100

I want to generate a table within the PHP Mail which lists values from **ALL** rows available in the table.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","ABC1234!","my_krty");//database connection


$date = date('Y-m-d');
$e_date = date('d-m-Y');

//Email Receiver//
   $to = "xxx@example.com";

   //From Header//
   $header = "From: MyKrty<undelivered@example.com>"."\r\n";
   $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";

   // Subject //
   $subject = "Request";


   // Message //
   $message = "<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' />
    </head>
    <body style='font-family: ' varela=''>

        <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='5' style='background-color:#f2f2f2; border-radius:5px; color:#333333; padding:7px; width:85%;'>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style='text-align: center;'>
                        <strong>Tracking AWB</strong></td>
                    <td style='text-align: center;'><strong>
                        Order ID #</strong></td>

                </tr>";
$get_ndr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `oc_ndr_confirm` WHERE `status`='0'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_ndr))
{
$order_id = $row['order_id'];
$tracking_no = $row['tracking_no'];
foreach($row as $value){

$message. = "<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><strong>".$value['tracking_no']."</td><td style='text-align:center;'>".$value['order_id']."</td></tr>";
        }}

$message.= "            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>

        <p>
            We request you to kindly re-schedule the following above at your earliest.</p>

    </body>
</html> \r\n";    

   //Send Mail//
   $mail_send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

I've tried a lot of Threads, but unable to figure out, as I don't understand arrays much. The mail function is working fine, but I'm just receiving one row only in the table, with values as 2 in both columns.

The last thread I referred to was **[How to Send Email with all Products in the Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271599/sending-email-with-all-products-from-cart)** .

Though, I couldn't make it referring the above mentioned thread as it was too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 small edits to your code.
First a small error in your html.
Secondly you have a while loop already where you set your db values in your variables. No extra foreach loop is needed.

```
 <body style='font-family:  varela'>


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_ndr)) {
  $order_id = $row['order_id'];
  $tracking_no = $row['tracking_no'];
  $message. = "<tr><td style='text-align:center;'><strong>".$tracking_no."</td><td style='text-align:center;'>".$order_id."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!